# How Get a 2 Legged Token Autodesk?

Tags: token, autodesk, 2-legged

I need to get "Get a 2-Legged Token" verification for a read-only access to upload files entered by other users but I'm running into the following error:

> {
> "developerMessage": "The required parameter(s) client_id,client_secret,grant_type not present in the request",
> "errorCode": "AUTH-008",
> "more info": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/"
> }

I followed exactly the example on the site changing just my "client id" and my "client secret":

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/

[image]

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The single quote  is wrong format in header of curl.

Try this format

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'client_id=your_client_id_xxx' \
-d 'client_secret=your_client_secret_xxx' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
-D 'scope=data:read'
```

It will be return access token
[image]

I am using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) for HTTP call.
It is more convenient
[image]